# Type Error on line 4: callback is not a function JavaScript callback

Tags: javascript

I created a forEach function that takes an array and a callback function, and runs the callback on each element of the array. The forEach function does not return anything. There is also a separate helper function map that is used.

```js
function forEach(array, callback) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    callback(array[i]);
  }
}

function map(array, callback) {
  let newArr = []
  forEach(array, newArr.push(callback));
  return newArr;
}

console.log(typeof forEach); // should log: 'function'
forEach(['a', 'b', 'c'], i => console.log(i)); // should log: 'a', 'b', 'c'
console.log(typeof map); // should log: 'function'
console.log(map([3, 4, 5], n => n - 2)); // should log: [1, 2, 3]
```

I get the following error: *Type Error on line 4: callback is not a function*
I'm quite close to resolving the issue but can't seem to figure out how to line 9 with the forEach function call. All test cases above pass, except the very last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resides in `forEach(array, newArr.push(callback));`. Try wrapping the second parameter, `newArr.push(callback)`, in an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
Resulting line will be `forEach(array, () => newArr.push(callback));`.

Here's a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-e1ewnv). Check out the console log.

Good luck!

Comment: Your code will not work. It will not return desired value as per question.

Comment: Taking a second look, you're right. I have now edited it in order to work as intended. Thanks for the notice!

Answer (score 2):

Change your `map` function to this:

```
function map(array, callback) {
   let newArr = []
   forEach(array, (value) => newArr.push(callback(value)));
   return newArr;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how the "(value) =>" works?  Trying to understand why it was running now and how rewriting it this way finally made it work. Thanks.

Comment: You may refer [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/#:~:text=What%20Are%20Arrow%20Functions%3F,way%20this%20binds%20in%20functions.) to learn more about arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write `return array.map(callback);` and it will work.

As [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) `map` accepts `callback` as `parameter` and you are already having `callback` function as `parameter`. All you need to do is `return array.map(callback);`.

Similarly you can do with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). But `forEach` doesn't return anything so you can not write `return array.forEach(callback);`. Instead of that you need to use it as `array.forEach(callback);`.

```js
function forEach(array, callback) {
  array.forEach(callback);
}

function map(array, callback) {
  return array.map(callback);
}

console.log(typeof forEach); // should log: 'function'
forEach(['a', 'b', 'c'], i => console.log(i)); // should log: 'a', 'b', 'c'
console.log(typeof map); // should log: 'function'
console.log(map([3, 4, 5], n => n - 2)); // should log: [1, 2, 3]
```